# Issues with deserialized json and xaml data binding in c#

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, datacontext

I'm trying to convert a powershell WPF application I built to C#, but I'm running into an issue with the datacontext/data binding.

In my many searches I ran across the following sample code, but when I implemented it, the properties show up via intellisense to bind in the XAML but nothing seems to actually bind.  I'm not sure what is wrong.  I'm new to C# (some VB.net/Powershell background), so it's likely me just not understanding something.

Deserialization code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1

{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window7.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class Window7 : Window

    {
        public Window7()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string jsonString = @"{
                        'Name' : 'Apple',  
                        'ExpiryDate' : '2018-01-02',
                        'Price' : 3.99
                        }";

            try
            {
                JsonClass jsonClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(jsonString);
                DataContext = jsonClass;    // I don't understand the point of this line. 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public class JsonClass

    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
   }
}
```

XAML reference

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window7"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window7" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:JsonClass/>    # This seems to point to a Class definition, not an actual instance.
    </Window.DataContext>
        
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

In my case, with VS 2022 and C# I'm my syntax is slightly different but not sure that matters.  I'm really not understanding the following line in the code though:

`DataContext = jsonClass;`

I assume this is setting the window's datacontext to the instance of JsonClass named jsonClass (lowercase json), but the XML specifically specifies the class itself (capital JsonClass) so I'm not following where the json data I deserialized is actually being used.

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:JsonClass/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: <local:JsonClass/> would create a new instance of JsonClass which does't have the data that you want, try removing the XAML part since you already did dataContext assignment in code behind

Comment: Ah that worked, at least when ran.  Is there a way to see these bound values in the actual designer?

Comment: while the window is selected in the designer go to Format>set design-time data context and you will find options for what type to use as DataContext in design time and whether to generate dummy data or use the actual class with the default constructor

Comment: OK I see that, but I want it to use the same context I've already built and deserialized in the code behind.  Is that possible?  I don't see any options to do that.

Alternatively, is there a way for me to statically set/initialize this information outside of the code behind, e.g. directly in the XAML?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to statically set/initialize this information outside of the code behind, e.g. directly in the XAML?

You can set the *design time* `DataContext` to an instance of a class like this:

```
<Window ...
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:JsonClass, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        >
```

You can then implement this class to return design time values:

```
public class JsonClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Apple";
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; } = new DateTime(2018, 1, 2);
    public decimal Price { get; set; } = 3.99m;
}
```

But you should not rely on the designer to verify runtime behaviour.

> I totally get the d:DataContext is the way...I'm simply asking if it's possible to point the DataContext for both runtime and design time to the same view model instance?

This, i.e. instantiating the `DataContext` in the XAML seems to work:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:JsonClass x:Key="viewModel" Name="Test" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="viewModel" />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
</Grid>
```

If you get the values of the properties dynamically, you could try to retrive the resource in the code-behind and set the properties of it. Then you should probably also implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`interface.

But I would recommend you to use a design time context using `d:DataContext` and not adopt your code to the Visual Studio designer...

Comment: I understand I can initialize the design dc to **an instance**.  It is my understanding that defining it that way, a new, and unpopolated instance would be created.

The whole goal in this is to bind my controls to a backend datacontext set with default values at launch, but I also want to visualize how those same settings look as I'm designing.

I was able to do this in Powershell as this started as a Powershell WPF app, that I'm now converting to C#.  Granted the visual designer I was using was PoshGUI.com.  I just assumed VS would also be able to do this.

Comment: So, I decided to try something different and just set default values on the JsonClass members and removed the entire deserialization I was doing in code.

I added back the datacontext binding in the XAML, originally posted above, and runtime still works, yet for reasons I don't understand, the designer is taking on the same context as well (though only after a build).  This is better than nothing.

Comment: That seems rude and unnecessary. I'm clearly lost in the thought process, hence the entire point of this thread/post.

I totally get the d:DataContext is the way. I'm not trying to subvert that. I'm simply asking if it's possible to point the DataContext for both runtime and design time to the same view model instance?  If so, how?  Can the context/model be set in XAML entirely vs having to use code-behind.  My properties are literally just control properties that I am setting with default values and changing later via code.

Comment: @MatthewMcDonald: Right. See my edit.